# awk or sed use to search a word between two Strings

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have two documents.... both has the same pattern. starting with \subsection and ending with end{center}.

I need to find if given vulnerability for example "xoxoxoxoxox", what are the number which has that number or rather the string.

I tried using

```
awk -v RS="" '/\\subsection.*SSL.*\\end{center}/ {print $13}' file
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could reduce your sample files down to the minimum size that reproduces the problem and included them here. It might also help you work out what was wrong for yourself.

Comment: I tried that too.... but what every i tried it will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the blank lines in the file are not always completely blank, but contain spaces. Try setting `RS` like so:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\n([[:space:]]*\n)+"} ...`
```

Comment: your a life saver..... but nevertheless, do u know why sometimes the character $13 shows $12 or $14 character?

Comment: `$13` always refers to the 13th field, so maybe the IP address is not always the 13th space-separated field in your data. However, if I run the following on the two files you've linked to, the 13th field is always the IP address: `awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n([[:space:]]*\n)+"} {print $13}'`

Comment: FYI this is gawk-specific thanks to the multi-char RS.

Comment: @EdMorton Right. I always forget that. Still, anyone with such an impotent awk should upgrade to gawk!

Comment: I have one small error. i run the your code, it successfully works in Linux cinnamon, but the same thing when i run it on Kubuntu, it does not work. same error occurs and read only the 1st record

Comment: @LoshWick I don't even *want* to know the differences between "cinnamon" and "kubuntu"! Is Kubuntu running gawk? What version is it? (Enter: gawk --version)